# Cybersource Error, Security Data : UsernameToken authentication failed

Tags: django, python-2.7, payment-gateway, django-oscar

Iam using cybersource for credit card payment.

Created username token for security data with the test account created

When Executing

```
    self.response = self.client.service.runTransaction(**options)
```

Gets error

```
    Server raised fault: '
    Security Data : UsernameToken authentication failed.
    '
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it.......

Just Generate transaction security key and give the generated key as password.
Able to connect successfully.

Steps to create key

```
Using a web browser, navigate to the CyberSource Enterprise Business Center (EBC) Test Environment login page
Log in using a username with Administrator credentials
Click Account Management from the menu bar on the left side of the screen
Click Transaction Security Keys In the expanded sub-menu,
Click the link, Security Keys for the Simple Order API on the Transaction Security Keys page
Click Generate Key

At this point you may see a pop-up dialog box asking if you want to block dynamic content on the page. Select No if this dialog box appears.

Click Generate Certificate Request when it appears (it may take a few seconds to load)

When the key generation script is done, a dialog box will appear which asks you to select a location on your computer where the new security key will be saved.

Save the key (the naming convention is <your merchant id>.p12)
Deploy the key to your system
```

Comment: what is the host url to be given when asked.